# misplaced & in equation using non-ams format

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

the following code works with ams environment, however I am trying to use it using aip conference template found here: http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/proceeding/aipcp/info/authors and it is complaining about a misplaced alignment tab character in the 3rd line.

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq:sinuramp}
I(x)= 
\begin{cases} s(x) & \text{if $x \le L/n$,} 
\\
s'(L/n)*x - s'(L/n)*L/n+s(L/n) &\text{if $x>L/2$.}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

Additionally, this code was output with mathematica.. and other equations work just fine as long as they do not have the '&' character. thank you.

Comment: Just add `\usepackage{amsmath}` to the document preamble.

Comment: Please post a complete MWE (minimum working example, or, in this case, minimum nonworking examplt) - the smallest file you can build that reproduces the problem -- unless @Werner 's comment solves the problem.

Comment: This does work, I will take it up with the editors later. Thanks friends.

Comment: Loading `mathtools` (which loads `amsmath`), you can use the `cases*` environment, for whhich you don't have to typeset `text` after `&`: it is already supposed to be in text mode.

Answer (score 1):

You probably just need to load `amsmath`, as in the second line below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:sinuramp}
I(x)=
\begin{cases} s(x) & \text{if $x \le L/n$,}
\\
s'(L/n)*x - s'(L/n)*L/n+s(L/n) &\text{if $x>L/2$.}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```